# Line treatment in C#

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I have some problems with string manipulation. I have some string in my input:

```
var firstString = "Endi Marrei";
var SecondString = "Spain";
```

I need to concat these two strings, for example:

```
Output  =  "Marrei E. (Spa)";
```

I tried this:

```
var d = firstString.Split(' ');
var dd = firstString[0].ToString();
var Output = d[1] + " " + dd + "." +" " + "(" + "???" + ")";
```

How can I cut Spain to third element?

That is, even though my way is working, do you know a more clean solution?

Comment: "even though my way is working," -- is it? You get `"Marrei E. (???)"` when your question asks for `"Marrei E. (Spa)"`, do you not?

Comment: I have run my code in Visual Studio and it works. Try running it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is "*do you know more clean solution*".
Well... my answer is that:
I suppose that you was assumed that all 3letterCode of each country is created by first 3 letters of country (like `SPAin => SPA`) ... and so on. The approach's wrong, look here:
http://www.worldatlas.com/aatlas/ctycodes.htm

Back to code:

```
public class CountriesFactory
{
    private static List<Country> _countries = new List<Country>()
    {
        new Country("Spain", "Spa"),
        new Country("Germany", "Ger")
    }

    public static Country GetCountryByName(string countryName)
    {
        return _countries.Where(p => p.CountryName == countryName).FirstOrDefault() ?? Country.NONE;
    }
}

public class Country
{
    public string CountryName { get; private set; }
    public string ThreeLetterCode { get; private set; }

    public const Country NONE = new Country("", "");

    public Country (string countryName, string threeLetterCode)
    {
        this.CountryName = countryName;
        this.ThreeLetterCode = threeLetterCode;
    }
}

public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public Country Country { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("{0} {1}. ({2})", Name, Surname[0].ToString(), Country.ThreeLetterCode);
    }
}
```

There's some conditions which should you add, but it's not important now.

Use in code:

```
Person person = new Person()
{
    Name = "Endi",
    Surname = "Marrei",
    Country = CountriesFactory.GetCountryByName("Spain")
}

Console.WriteLine(person.ToString());
```

by your example:

```
var firstString = "Endi Marrei";
var SecondString = "Spain";
var person = new Person()
{
    Name = firstString.Split(' ')[0].ToString(),
    Surname = firstString.Split(' ')[1].ToString(),
    Country = CountriesFactory.GetCountryByName(SecondString)
}
```

I think that my approach will be more useful in the future.

Answer (score 0):

`even though your code is working`..so I would guess, you are looking for a cleaner way of doing it (and not one liner). simple suggestion would be to not to use `+` operator to concatenate strings and spaces. Try using `String.Format` for cleaner code

```
var firstString = "Endi Marrei";
var SecondString = "Spain";
var parts = firstString.Split(' ');
var d = String.Format("{0} {1}.", parts[1], parts[0][0].ToString().ToUpper());
var dd = String.Format("({0})", SecondString.Substring(0, 3));
var output = String.Format("{0} {1}", d, dd);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regex, although it's debatable whether this is a cleaner approach.

```
var match = Regex.Match(firstString + " " + secondString, @"(\w)\S*\s+(\w+)\s+(\w{3})");
var output = match.Success
                ? string.Format("{1} {0}. ({2})",
                    match.Groups[1], match.Groups[2], match.Groups[3])
                : string.Empty;
Console.WriteLine(output);

// output: Marrei E. (Spa)
```

[Demo.](https://repl.it/C3ub)

Answer (score -1):

```
var firstString = "Endi Marrei";
var SecondString = "Spain";

var d = firstString.Split(' ');<br/>
var Output = d[1] + " " + d[0][0] + "." + " " + "(" + SecondString.Substring(0, 3) + ")";
```

d[0][0] is the same as firstString[0].ToString();

Comment: If you use the code block formatting (i.e. four spaces at the start of each line) it'll be a lot more readable. It would also help if you extend your answer with a short explanation.

Comment: I have run my code in Visual studio and it works. Try running it